# Dynamic Points with shading

Tags: c#, mschart

I am programming in C# on VB2010 and I am wanting to shade under the line that is made on my chart. I have a chart with 7 separate values on the X-axis and adjust them with a trackbar for the height on the Y-axis. First I would like to know how to have my line (I'm currently using the `Spline` type `Series` chart) display shading under where the line is to the bottom of my chart; and to also have my chart display the new value on the chart immediately after moving the trackbar so that I don't have to click on the chart to update the display.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a link to your images.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/123594293@N07/